# Provision lambda concurrency in CDK typescript

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cdk, aws-cdk-typescript

I am trying to provision lambda concurrency via CDK. I don't want to create new veesion of lambda inside existing lambda provision concurrency should be added.

Below code is creating new version which I don't required

```
new lambda.Function(this, 'lambda1', {
            code: new lambda.InlineCode('exports.handler = async () => { console.log(\'hello world\'); };'),
            handler: 'index.handler',
            runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_10_X,
            currentVersionOptions: {
                provisionedConcurrentExecutions: 3
            }
        })
```

Comment: Per [Creating function versions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-versions.html#configuration-versions-config): "When you publish a version, Lambda locks the code and most of the settings to maintain a consistent experience for users of that version."

Comment: @jarmod I don't want to publish new version. Wanted to make change without versioning. How to do this?

Comment: Understood but I suspect that you cannot. You want to change a setting but you can only do that on an unpublished version of the function.

Comment: So we have to publish new version? is there any other way to do this ?

Comment: Perhaps you could elaborate on why you want to do this. The versioning feature is designed to provide stability for clients.

Comment: I want to add provision concurrency for my existing lambda in current version

Comment: As far as I can tell, you cannot do this. Repeatedly saying "but I want to do it" won't change that, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Provisioned concurrency requires a separate version - that is, one that is not `$LATEST`. From the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/provisioned-concurrency.html):

> You cannot use provisioned concurrency with the $LATEST version of any function.